# C# Cross-Thread communication

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates

in C#.NET , I've written the following simple background worker thread:

```
public class MyBackgrounder
{
    public delegate void dlgAlert();
    public dlgAlert Alert;
    public event EventHandler eventAlert;
    Thread trd;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (trd == null || trd.ThreadState == ThreadState.Aborted)
        {
            trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Do));
        }
        trd.IsBackground = true;
        trd.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
        trd.Start();
    }

    void Do()
    {

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Done();
    }

    void Done()
    {
        if (Alert != null)
            Alert();
        if (eventAlert != null)
            eventAlert(this, new EventArgs());
        Kill();
    }

    public void Kill()
    {
        if (trd != null)
            trd.Abort();
        trd = null;
    }
}


static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        MyBackgrounder bg = new MyBackgrounder();
        bg.eventAlert += new EventHandler(bg_eventAlert);
        bg.Alert = jobDone;
        bg.Start();
    }

    static void bg_eventAlert(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here, current thread's id has been changed
    }

    static void jobDone()
    { 
        // here, current thread's id has been changed
    }

}
```

It just waits for 3 seconds (does its job) and then raises an specified event or calls a delegate. there's no problem until here and everything works fine. But when i watch the '**Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId**' , i see it's the background thread! maybe it's normal , but how can i prevent this behavior? if you test the '**System.Windows.Forms.Timer**' component and handle its '**Tick**' event , you can see that the '**Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId**' has not been changed from main thread Id to anything else.

what can i do?

Comment: There is no problem in your code and you just want to understand, right? The backgroundworker **is** in another thread. Where do you watch the thread id?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Timer uses internal Windows WM_TIMER event and simply counts number of ticks, then raises the .NET event. Therefore it can work in main thread of process. The background worker you wrote works in background thread (explicitly by creating new Thread()), overwise the Thread.Sleep(3000) would suspend all your application. What is the problem with this running in background thread exactly?

Comment: @MareInfinitus , when the background worker object raises its event or calls the specified method, there, i see the changed thread id. it means that my background worker has called those methods.

Comment: Thats right, the called methods are not in the background worker thread but in the thread that provides those callbacks.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, Thanks. I want to solve (change) the background worker behavior , so I'l be safe later interacting UI elements. it seems that i must write the Backgrounder using native Win APIs just like .NET's Timer, not? but how it works in an independent class without using threads!?

Comment: There is no need to do so. You can interact with UI from background thread as long as you stick to Microsoft's rules. :-) Please consult this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx Also I guess it wouldn't be possible to use Forms.Timer in non-UI thread as it is UI-control.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, I've worked the solution you mentioned by MSDN link before , but i don't want to write more code lines (safety checking code) for every control on my forms and user controls. i just wanted to solve the problem once. I think i must get help from my UI Form to obtain a timer tick using its Timer component. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You don't need to write a lot safety checking code actually. All you need to to is give your MyBackgrounder class a reference to Form and always wrap Alert/eventAlert delegates in this Form's Invoke. There is no reason why you should avoid executing the delegate in UI's thread even if the delegate does not change anything in UI actually. :-)

Comment: @KubaWyrostek , The MyBackgrounder class and its caller are both in one layer separate from UI layer. this is the scenario: A UI Form (layer1) uses a non-UI class (layer2) to do something. layer2 itself needs a timer to handle the specified timeout during its job. because layer1 has a reference to layer2, i can't give layer2 a reference to layer1 again.

Comment: OK, I've posted another solution in answers here. Please review if this would fit your needs.

Answer (score 5):

If You are using Windows Forms you can do something like this:

1. In your Form add property

   ```
   private readonly System.Threading.SynchronizationContext context;
   public System.Threading.SynchronizationContext Context
   {
       get{ return this.context;}
   }
   ```
2. In Your Form constructor set the property

   ```
   this.context= WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
   ```
3. Use this property to pass it to Your background worker as a constructor parameter. This way your worker will know about your GUI context. Create similar property inside Your background worker.

   ```
   private readonly System.Threading.SynchronizationContext context;
   public System.Threading.SynchronizationContext Context
   {
       get{ return this.context;}
   }

   public MyWorker(SynchronizationContext context)
   {
       this.context = context;
   }
   ```
4. Change your `Done()` method:

   ```
   void Done()
   {
       this.Context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(DoneSynchronized), null);
   }

   void DoneSynchronized(object state)
   {
       //place here code You now have in Done method.
   }
   ```
5. In DoneSynchronized You should always be in Your GUI thread.

Comment: Nice solution. Please note that BackgroundWorker's Context property should be readonly or have its setter synchronized.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek True that! I changed the properties.

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura,Thanks for your help,
but if i decide to have a reference to "System.Windows.Forms" in my underlying layer , don't you think it's better 
to use the "Timer" component instead of "WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext"? 
i've tested it and it works fine , cause the top running application is a windows form.
i think it's more easier to use.

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura please take a look at my own answer. thanks a lot for your help my friend.

Comment: @losingsleeep `SynchronizationContext` is in mscorlib.dll so I think You don't need to reference System.Windows.Forms.dll in background worker project if it's implemented that way.

Answer (score 1):

The Timer runs in the main thread (and will be late going off if the main thread is really busy). If for some reason you want jobDone() to be called from the main thread you could for instance use a BackGroundWorker object which is threaded internally and has some specific events that are called threadsafe with the main thread (allowing UI updates etc.)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it that bugs you with the background thread? What you describe, looks fine for me so far.

The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` that you checked for comparison might be running **on the UI thread**, which indeed would make it a non-background thread.

From MSDN documentation of the [Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property (highlights by me):

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads **are identical** to foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete.

Comment: **Any remaining threads are stopped and do not complete**  - I guess these all throw ThreadAbortException

Answer (score 0):

How about this design:

1. Create an EventWaitHandle object in your Form.

   ```
   private EventWaitHandle layer2changed =
       new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
   ```
2. In a Timer event handler do the following:

   ```
   if (this.layer2changed.WaitOne(0, false))
   {
       // perform UI updates according to some public properties of layer1/layer2
       this.layer2changed.Reset();
   }
   ```
3. Pass the reference to layer2changed to layer1/layer2 etc. in their constructors.
4. Every time your Done() method does something that requires updating UI signal an event:

   ```
    this.referencedLayer2Changed.Set();
   ```

Please note however, that there will be time difference between the changes in layer2 and UI (the longer the Form.Timer interval - the longer the difference).

**Note to everybody: this a soley a solution emerging from additional requirements specified by losingsleep in comments to his question. Please read them prior to downvoting. :-)**

Answer (score 0):

I think there's another solution that does not need a reference to "System.Windows.Forms" in underlying layer (layer2):
layer1 (UI form) delivers a timeout implementation that layer2 can use.

there's an Interface:

```
namespace Layer2
{
    public delegate void TimeoutAlert();

    public interface IApplicationContext
    {
        void SetTimeout(TimeoutAlert timeoutAlerthandler, int milliseconds);
    }
}
```

and working class in Layer2:

```
namespace Layer2
{
    public class Worker
    {
        IApplicationContext _context;
        public void DoJob(IApplicationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _context.SetTimeout(JobTimedOut,3000);
            // nothing ... (wait for other devices or user events)
        }

        void JobTimedOut()
        {
            // do something suitable for timeout error with _context or anything else
        }

    }
}
```

and at UI, we have this:

```
using Layer2;

namespace Layer1
{
    public partial class frmTest : Form, IApplicationContext
    {

        int timeout;
        TimeoutAlert _timeoutAlerthandler;

        public frmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Worker w = new Worker();
            w.DoJob(this);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // it's the handler of 'Timer' component named 'timer1'
            timer1.Enabled = false;

            if (_timeoutAlerthandler != null)
                _timeoutAlerthandler();
        }

        #region IApplicationContext Members

        void IApplicationContext.SetTimeout(TimeoutAlert timeoutAlerthandler, int milliseconds)
        {
            _timeoutAlerthandler = timeoutAlerthandler;
            timeout = milliseconds;

            timer1.Interval = milliseconds;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

I notice my scenario again:
I have a windows application project (layer1) that uses a core project (layer2) to do some works. the core needs non-blocking timeout checks during some of its methods without creating a different thread , cause after timeout it needs to interact with the UI again. sorry if i can't describe more because it's a little complex (for me!).

Comment: Timer tick is blocking the main thread. There isn't something like non-blocking code execution without different thread in one application domain.

Comment: Yes Grzegorz. In this example, except the Timer component everything is blocking, and it's not a problem for me. i just wanted use a timeout without creating another thread.