# Cross-thread operation not valid:

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my application I had a requirement of notifying the user about the pending applications.

So in the `mdiParent` I set a `BackgroundWorker` which keeps querying the database to get any pending application, and if it finds any display it on the Tooltip on the `MdiParent`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(2000);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    fillnotification();
}    

public void fillnotification()
{
    int pending = 0;
    if( Program.USERPK != 0)
    {    
        DataTable dt = nftrans.getnotification();
        pending = dt.Rows.Count;

        String message = "You Have  " + pending + " Applications Pending For Approval";

        // toolTip1.SetToolTip(lblStatus , message);
        toolTip1.Show(message , this, lblStatus.Location);
    }
}
```

but when I run the solution I am getting an exception:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MainForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I understand its due to two different threads but cannot sort this out. Can any one suggest a solution? I tried the ideas I read in related questions But cannot find a correct solution

Comment: yes winform application

Comment: [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273562/c-sharp-cross-thread-communication/11274317#11274317)

Comment: ***Please*** at least *look* at the thousands of other identical questions before you ask the same one again? Please?

Comment: I checked the qstns but I cannot find anyone related to  tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change fillnotification() to return your pending value and pass that to "e.Result" in your DoWork() handler.  Now wire up the RunWorkerCompleted() event and retrieve the result of your background operation:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = fillnotification();
    }

    public int fillnotification()
    {
        if (Program.USERPK != 0)
        {
            DataTable dt = nftrans.getnotification();
            return dt.Rows.Count;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        int pending = (int)e.Result;
        if (pending != -1)
        {
            String message = "You Have  " + pending.ToString() + " Applications Pending For Approval";
            toolTip1.Show(message, this, lblStatus.Location);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you are accessing a control from an outside thread (the background worker [Executes an operation on a separate thread.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)) you need to do some sort of invoke.  This executes a delegate on the thread that owns the underlying window handle.

Something simple like ;

```
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
        //   toolTip1.SetToolTip(lblStatus , message);
        toolTip1.Show(message, this, lblStatus.Location);

        }));
```

Will probably work for your case, as long as your previous code is not accessing controls, I'm not sure what `getnotification()` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the UI (tooltip) on the worker thread.

That is not allowed. Use the UI thread to change the tooltip by calling Invoke on the Window and passing a delegate to a function that changes the the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that the change of tooltip happens at the exact end of your worker thread, you could use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event - you CAN modify the UI thread from there, and that's what this event was designed for.

Of course Chris Bucklers `Invoke` solution will also work.