# Pass data from UI thread to another thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

How do I pass data from main thread to the method which is running in a different thread continuously? I have a timer in which the value will be continuously incremented and that data will have do be passed to the method in a different thread at each timer tick event. Please help. I don't have much knowledge about threading.

Comment: Show us what you have already done? There are few ways in C# to invoke a thread, which one do you use?

Comment: Sir,i haven't done much more & all codes are messed up. please suggest me some idea.

Comment: You are using Winforms ? Please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273562/c-sharp-cross-thread-communication

Comment: @SriramSakthivel:  no sir,I want to do its reverse process without loosing any data.

Comment: Post your code how you use threads. I'll try to answer. Is it a infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue to send data to the other thread, which you lock for access. This ensures that all data sent to the other thread is eventually processed. You don't really need to think of it as "sending" data to the other thread but managing a lock on shared data so that they don't access it at the same time (which could cause disaster!)

```
Queue<Data> _dataQueue = new Queue<Data>();

void OnTimer()
{
    //queue data for the other thread
    lock (_dataQueue)
    {
        _dataQueue.Enqueue(new Data());
    }
}

void ThreadMethod()
{
    while (_threadActive)
    {
        Data data=null;
        //if there is data from the other thread
        //remove it from the queue for processing
        lock (_dataQueue)
        {
            if (_dataQueue.Count > 0)
                data = _dataQueue.Dequeue();
        }

        //doing the processing after the lock is important if the processing takes
        //some time, otherwise the main thread will be blocked when trying to add
        //new data
        if (data != null)
            ProcessData(data);

        //don't delay if there is more data to process
        lock (_dataQueue)
        {
            if (_dataQueue.Count > 0)
                continue;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Windows Forms you can do something like this:

In your Form add property

```
private readonly System.Threading.SynchronizationContext context;
public System.Threading.SynchronizationContext Context
{
    get{ return this.context;}
}
```

In Your Form constructor set the property

```
this.context= WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Use this property to pass it to Your background worker as a constructor parameter. This way your worker will know about your **GUI context**. Create similar property inside **your background worker**.

```
private readonly System.Threading.SynchronizationContext context;
public System.Threading.SynchronizationContext Context
{
    get{ return this.context;}
}

public MyWorker(SynchronizationContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

Change your Done() method:

```
void Done()
{
    this.Context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(DoneSynchronized), null);
}

void DoneSynchronized(object state)
{
    //place here code You now have in Done method.
}
```

In DoneSynchronized You should always be in Your GUI thread.

The above answer is exactly from this thread. Duplicate Marked.

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273562/c-sharp-cross-thread-communication)